# jupiter cannot import name 'TransformerSummarizer' from 'summarizer'

Tags: python-3.x, package, bert-language-model

I've been trying to follow this article and install transformers and summarizer https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/text-summarization-using-bert-gpt2-xlnet-5ee80608e961

However, I keep getting this error

```
cannot import name 'TransformerSummarizer' from 'summarizer' 
 (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\summarizer\__init__.py)
```

while trying to run this line

```
from summarizer import Summarizer, TransformerSummarizer
```

I uninstalled and installed anaconda, updated every package possible, but its still doesn't work. I tried to find similar questions, however all their solutions still won't help me. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please share, I am out of ideas!

Comment: Can you please link to the solutions that you have already tried, in order for people to know what not to suggest?
Also, to clarify: The error message is all that appears, correct? Have you tried running `from summarizer.bert import Summarizer` instead?

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by the files in the path specified.
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\summarizer_*init*_.py
Change the summarizer folder with the folder from this git https://github.com/ApacheNaren/Summarizer